# Playing sound on cards

Tags: react-native, react-native-sound

I have application with cards on stack (a lot of cards - about 500)

I card component I added:

```
function getVoice() {
    try {
        const mySound = new Sound(getSoundName(id), Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE,
            (error) => {
                if (error) {
                    Alert.alert('Error:', error.message)
                    return;
                }
            })

        if (mySound != null) {
            mySound.play((success, error) => {
                if (success) {
                    Alert.alert('success')
                } else {
                    Alert.alert('err')
                }
                mySound.release()
            })
        }
    }
    catch{

    }
};
```

An alert is triggered here `err`

What is wrong?

I tried another option.

I called `new Sound()` at the beginning of component loading

Here the sound was playing but works on up to 8 cards. Later there is the same mistake as now

Answer (score 0):

It works fine:

```
const getVoice = () => {
    try {
        const sound = new Sound(getSoundName(id), null, (error) => {
            if (error) {
                return;
            }

            sound.play();
        });
    }
    catch{
    }
};
```